# Install4j: How to change java default icon

Tags: install4j

In `Install4j`, how can I change the Java icon default in error popups displayed during the installation.

Please see the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Does the installer window also have a Java cup icon? Is this a message configured in the "Error message" property of an action?

Comment: In Windows, there is no icon before the windows title. Java cup icon is only shown in Linux versions. The message error is displayed by using the API : Util.showOptionDialog

Comment: Most window managers do not show icons for message dialogs, I don't have a Linux distribution that does that. We use a standard JOptionPane call with the wizard window as the parent. If the option pane does not pick up the icon frame of the parent, I'm not sure what we could do.